# Cannot parse date string containing three letter month

Tags: android, parsing, datetime-format

I spent about hour to solve problem, but I couldn't...

My date string is "06 Jan 2016", and I want to parse it to object Date.

I tried next method

```
SimpleDateFormat frmt2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");   
Date date = frmt2.parse("06 Jan 2016");
```

And I got:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06 Jan 2016" (at offset 3)
```

I tried Joda lib

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("06 Jan 2016");
```

But I got same error:

```
Invalid format: "06 Jan 2016" is malformed at "Jan 2016"
```

Can you help me please to obtain the success in this simple problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply because `06 JAN 2016` is not a valid date. Try `2016-01-06`, instead.

Comment: Date string should be `06 Jan 2016`

Comment: What's your Locale? That's probably not a valid format for your default. It is valid in, for example, `Locale.US`.

Comment: Sorry! this string from my experiments. However, my question is still about the correct line. "06 Jan 2016"

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date theDate = format.parse("JAN 13,2014  09:15");

    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    myCal.setTime(theDate);

    System.out.println("Day: " + myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("Month: " + myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    System.out.println("Year: " + myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I had to specify the Locale. I have all earned.

Comment: Had you test on **Jan-24-2016**

Comment: @Rinnion - That's correct. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)